# Using WMI and PYWIN32 to change IPV4 settings on Ethernet card

Tags: python, network-programming, wmi, pywin32

Im trying to change the IPV4 adress on the Ethernet-card.
But when i run the script only the subnetmask changes and the IPV4 settings 
remain on "obtain an IP address automaticly".
Any clue?

Info: The `var_ip`, `var_mask`, `var_gateway` comes from entry widgets.

```
import wmi

def set_ip():

nic_configs = wmi.WMI().Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration(IPEnabled=True)

# First network adaptor
nic = nic_configs[0]
ip = var_ip.get()
subnetmask = var_mask.get()
gateway = var_gateway.get()

# Set IP address, subnet mask and default gateway
a = nic.EnableStatic(IPAddress=[ip], SubnetMask=[subnetmask])
b = nic.SetGateways(DefaultIPGateway=[gateway])
```

Comment: Looking on my old C# code where I tried to do this using WMI, I see that finally it was replaced by `netsh` command. So I just use CreateProcess and pass required parameters to `netsh`.

Comment: Is it possible to integrate my variables in a netsh command?

Comment: Thanks! Reformat your answer so i can mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one of my projects I also tried to do this using WMI, finally changed this to using `netsh` program. You can use `CreateProcess` and pass required parameters to `netsh`. 
For example, assuming that Etnernet adapter name is `eth1`, command-line utility `netsh` can be used by the following way:

```
netsh interface ipv4 set address "eth1" dhcp

netsh interface ipv4 set address "eth1" static 192.168.0.1 255.255.255.0
```

See also: https://www.howtogeek.com/103190/change-your-ip-address-from-the-command-prompt/